# How to configure gradle to resolve dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, subproject

i am trying to move my `MAVEN` build to a `gradle`
therefore i need to solve the following:

project:

- application (this one shall create a fatjar)

plugins (shall result in single jar files, but no fat jars!)

- utils (requires: jarX, jarY, jarZ)
- data (requires: utils, jarX, jarY)
- controls (requires: data, utils, jarY)

what i worked out is create a jar for each plugin (but i have to **FULLY** define its dependecies, which is actually `gradle`s job

so what i did was create jar files, copy them manually to a `reposiory` and declare dependencies on those...

so what i expected is, that i only have to tell application to require controls, because controls already includes anything needed (alsways includes the dependencies from stuff below)

i guess i have to define a project (yes i read the help page of gradle, but i was not able to work it out)

so right now i have settings.gradle in each plugin, but what i read this is wrong.
i should only have one settings.gradle in the root.

ROOT: settings.gradle:

```
include ':application', ':controls', ':data', ':util'
```

ROOT: build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.glazedlists:glazedlists:1.11.0'
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq:3.12.1'
        classpath 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:8.40.12'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and each of the plugins got:
build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

but this does not work either...

thanks in advance

Comment: The dependencies block of the buildscript block defines the dependencies needed by the build script, i.e. by the gradle tasks themselves. Not the dependencies of your projects. Read https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html#header (for example), and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#header

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? What problems are you facing?

Comment: It does not resolve the plugins of the included plugins

Comment: That language is confusing. By your first use of the word "plugin", do you mean [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html)? By the second use, do you mean [subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:subproject_configuration)? i.e. "_gradle is not resolving the **dependencies** of the included **subprojects**_".

Comment: i am sorry - i do develop an application (project) which has multiple parts (subprojects, eclipse would call this plugin) - dependencies might be jar files or other parts/subprojects/plugins

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to do a multiproject setup, do the following:

### settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'mvn2Gradle'
include ':application', ':controls', ':data', ':util'
```

### build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    ext {
        jarYVersion = '1.x'
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.example:jarY:$jarYVersion" // Every subproject gets this dependency
    }
}

wrapper { // Run this task once before you start building
    gradleVersion = '5.6.3'
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}
```

### `utils`: build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

ext {
    jarXVersion = '1.x'
    jarZVersion = '1.x'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.example:jarX:$jarXVersion"
    api "org.example:jarZ:$jarZVersion" // "api" because none of the other projects depends on this jar
}
```

### `data`: build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':utils') // Also inherits "jarX"
}
```

### `controls`: build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':data') // Also inherits "project:utils"
}
```

### `application`: build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

application {
    mainClassName 'my.package.Main'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':controls')
}
```